# How to make argument mandatory for script to run java application

Tags: java, shell, unix, classpath

My script is called `report_startDate`

It has the following line:

`$JRE_ROOT/bin/java -cp /home/me/report/config/:/home/me/report/jar/reporting-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  com.me.project.report.Main $1`

`$1` makes it possible to for me to run the script as `./report_startDate 20140717`.

But the script also runs without the date. I want to make it mandatory for whoever runs this script to supply the date. What could I replace `$1` with to make it mandatory to supply date.

I do not want to add logic to code, rather add logic to shell script as there are multiple scripts one with date one without date.

Answer (score 0):

in your `public static void main(String[] args)` method you should start with something like this.

```
if (args == null || args.length != 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("need one and only one input param...");
```

Comment: Will `args` ever be `null` ? :)

Comment: Didnt remember so put it in. No args will never be null

Comment: So what will it be if no arguments are passed? :)

Comment: You will have args length of 0 instead of 1 and you will get an IllegalArgumentException back to console

Comment: I am looking to see how this can be achieved in the script and not code. edited the question.

Comment: Check http://serverfault.com/questions/7503/how-to-determine-if-a-bash-variable-is-empty

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by `IllegalArgumentException`. You don't really need a link, all you have to do is print out `args.length` and `args.getClass()`. Why don't you fix your answer then ?

Answer (score 0):

you can check if there is a date in the first parameter , like this :

```
#first argument should test if the date is valid
date -d $1 &> /dev/null

#if exit code is 0 then the date is valid
if [[ "$?" ==  "0" ]] ; then
    #execute your java program with $1
else
    echo "please insert a date as first argument"
fi
```